# How to use a namespace alias (use) inside a class or function

Tags: php, class, namespaces

In my script, I have two classes with the name "Exception".

Normally, I would use

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
```

and then, use the class Exception that points to PHPMailer.

The problem is that I can't use the "use" command inside a function. So how can I declare what exception to use each time?

Example:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMAiler\PHPMailer\Exceptions;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

class email {
  function send_with_smtp {
     $a = new PHPMailer();  // inside this class it needs the exceptions to be used as a PHPMailer\Exceptions
  }

  function send_with_critsend{
     $a = new MXM(); // inside this class it needs the exceptions to be used NOT as a PHPMailer\Exceptions
  }
}
```

What I would do -but can't because use is used only in the upper level- is the following (that is wrong of course). But this is what I would like to achieve:

```
class email {
  function send_with_smtp {
     use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
     use PHPMAiler\PHPMailer\Exceptions;
     use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

     $a = new PHPMailer();  // inside this class it needs the exceptions to be used as a PHPMailer\Exceptions
  }

  function send_with_critsend{
     use ANOTHER; // maybe the default Exceptions or something else.
     $a = new MXM(); // inside this class it needs the exceptions to be used NOT as a PHPMailer\Exceptions
  }
}
```

Comment: As i noted before: Dont worrie about exceptions that other libs are using. Just use `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;` global (at the start of the current file), when you are doing `new PHPMailer();` in that file. Only if you want to `throw` an exception by yourself, you have to include it via  `use PHPMAiler\PHPMailer\Exception`. But all that can  be done global in a file or via fully qualified namespace in line.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you just reference the desired exception by its full name?

```
class alpha {
  function alphafunction {
     $a = new \PHPMailer\Exception\Exception();
  }
}

class beta {
  function betafunction {
     $a = new \AnotherClass\Exception\Exception();
  }
}
```

Comment: No, because the alphafunction and betafunction, call another class that needs to use  exception already declared in their own path

Answer (score 0):

On one side you can use different files for different classes that use different Exceptions.

alpha .php

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
class alpha {
  function alphafunction {
     throw new Exception();
  }
}
```

beta.php

```
use AnotherClass\Exception\Exception;
class beta{
  function alphafunction {
     throw new Exception();
  }
}
```

But you can also do in one file:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception as PHPMailerException ;
use AnotherClass\Exception\Exception as AnotherClassException;

class alpha {
  function alphafunction {
     throw new PHPMailerException();
  }
}

class beta {
  function betafunction {
     throw new AnotherClassException();
  }
}
```

Topic here: namespace aliases

If you want to know what exception you get from elsewhere do:

```
try {
  //do stuff here
} catch(\Exception $e){
  print get_class($e);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean of "different files for different class" ?
The problem is that I have to use the "exception" as it is used by other libraries.
I mean that alpha class call some other functions and classes.

Comment: @ALEX a `use X as Y;` line, is only used in the currend file. I update my answer a little.

Comment: I need to use the same "exception" as it is used by other libraries.
The phpmailer needs its own exception and the other library also needs its own exception. If I could use the "use" inside a function would solve the problem, but i can't since it needs to be in the upper level.

Comment: @ALEX `alpha class call some other functions and classes` You can ignore that. Because Namespaces are *file* based and whatever you `use` in the current file is only relevant in this *file*.  You can `use foo/bar as foobar;` and in a other file `use foo/bar as bazz;`. There is no conflict.

Comment: @ALEX "use" inside a function --> Then use fully qualified namespaces in the function e.g. `throw new \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception();`.

Comment: @ALEX I thing your question isnt clear enuff to give you an right answer. Currently i dont know, what you really want to achieve.

Comment: Use like a good workaround... my actual problem is the following:

I have a class named "email" that call a function "send_with_phpmailer" and another function "send_with_sendgrid" and another function "send_with_critsend".

phpmailer want to declare: use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception and the sendgrid also want to declare the Exception. If I put them in different files it could work, but isn't there any other way to say for example "This function use this class as exception" and in the other function of the same class to say "that function use the other class as exception"?

Comment: @ALEX Sendgrid has only one Exception : https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/5ddb5bf749f9731d5d43fe099f0371c77719d46f/lib/mail/TypeException.php   and that is not the same as `PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception` but both extend from the base php internal `Exception` class.

Comment: maybe i was not clear in my initial question. I edited the question, maybe its more clear now. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Thank you, Ill try in different files, since what I want can't be done this way ;) Thank you for your help!! :)

Answer (score -1):

To use a namespace alias (also called a "using directive") inside a class or function, you can place the using keyword followed by the namespace and the alias you want to use at the top of your class or function definition. For example:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class MyClass
    {
        // Use the alias "alias" for the namespace "MyNamespace::MyOtherNamespace"
        using alias = MyNamespace::MyOtherNamespace;

        void MyFunction()
        {
            // Use the alias to access a class or function in the namespace
            alias::MyClass instance;
            instance.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, the using directive creates an alias for the MyOtherNamespace namespace inside the MyNamespace namespace. This allows you to use the alias to access classes or functions in the MyOtherNamespace namespace without having to fully qualify their names.

Comment: This answer looks like generated by ChatGPT. Please be aware that [ChatGPT is currently banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).

Comment: This code snippet is quite general and doesn't apply the question, ChatGPT is that you?